# Disable read-out protection stm8s003

Tags: iar, stm8

I am starting to use stm8s003. I use the stm8s003 board like this:
"https://www.cnx-software.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/One_dollar_development_board.jpg".
When I use **IAR** and download the program to my stm8 this error occurs :

> "The Flash Memory Read-out protection option must be disabled for
>   debug. Disabling this option will first erase the whole Flash Memory."

and I can't debug. How do I disable read-out protection?

Comment: You have to modify options bytes, to disable ROP. To do that you can use STVP utility provided by ST. 
Change those option bytes in (3rd tab of STVP I guess) and burn the program once, from there afterwards, you won't be seeing this message, unless you explicitly do something which re-enables the ROP bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Read-out protection by reset option bytes(using ST-Link Utility) but I suppose your code will enable protection again, so you have to ensure that during debug session your code does not enable ReadOut protection. You can use Release/Debug configuration to manage this issue.